# Unable to install Python 3.x with anaconda

Tags: python, conda

I recently had anaconda installed on my work computer. It has come with python 2.7. I have tried to install 3.6 through the command line for anaconda. but I get the following error:

```
Error: HTTPError: 403 Forbidden http://rep.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
```

I cant figure out why this maybe, except maybe IT are blocking external installs.

Any idea on why would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't seem to access that URL. `Could not resolve host: rep.continuum.io`

Comment: Did you check with your IT department?

Comment: Yep. No assistance. Basic helpdesk.